# Text in first field shows as label for second field

Tags: php, html, text, synchronization

How do we make a text field sync with another text field i.e Adding text in first field shows as label for another text field.Basically i have made a currency exchange skeleton.

```
<form method='POST' action='index.php'>

    <div class="row uniform 50%">
          <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">

              <input type="text" name="from" value="" placeholder="From Which Currency?" tabindex="1" />
              <input type="hidden" name="owner" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" />
          </div>
          <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
              <input type="text" name="to" value="" placeholder="To Which Currency?" tabindex="2" />
          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform 50%">
          <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">

              <input type="text" name="limit" value="" placeholder="How much volume?" tabindex="3" />
          </div>
              <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
              <input type="text" name="fee" value="" placeholder="Your Fee or put Zero(Don't add %age sign)" tabindex="4" />
          </div>
                  <div class="6u 12u(mobilep)">
              <input type="text" name="price" value="" placeholder="Your Rate ( Don't add symbols)" tabindex="4" />
          </div>
    </div>
```

This is the result i currently see with this code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/48SZk.png

But i want to make it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA2Va.png

Comment: Please tell which place you want to insert that currency name. Field name please ?

Answer (score -1):

Add text of your textbox to label on the keyUp event of that textbox itself.

Comment: Hi @Sahil. You have enough reputation for giving suggestion in comment box. Correct ?

Comment: @user3265050 As Nana mentioned, please provide field names that is from where you want to get text and where you want to print that.

Comment: From Which Currency > Rate

1 (From Which Currency) = This should be label

Comment: $("#fromWhichCurrency").keyup(function(){
 var curVal = $("#fromWhichCurrency").val();
 $("#rate1").val(curVal);
});